# Unable to Save image in iOS device using Photo Libraby - ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, photolibrary

Error - ERROR: Method 'requestAuthorization:' not defined in Plugin 'PhotoLibrary' and
same issue facing for SaveImage Function.

Few details:

Ionic 3
Plugin version : PhotoLibrary ^2.2.1
Working fine in Android device but not working on iPhone 5s , iPhone 7(12.3.1) and other device.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library/issues/163
This is how i resolved it... its better to install the following plugins with correct versions and it will work perfectly.

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-photo-library

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@1.7.2
cordova plugin add https://github.com/nilebma/cordova-plugin-photo-library.git
```